# How to ceil the result for UInt division in Chisel

Tags: scala, chisel

As the title stated, how to do that?

```
val a = 3.U

val result = a / 2.U
```

result would be `1.U`

However I want to apply ceil on division.

```
val result = ceil(a / 2.U )
```

Therefore, I could get `2.U` of the result value.

Answer (score 1):

When dividing `a` by `b`, if you know that `a` is not too big (namely that `a <= UInt.MaxValue - (b - 1)`), then you can do

```
def ceilUIntDiv(a: UInt, b: UInt): UInt =
  (a + b - 1.U) / b
```

If `a` is potentially too big, then the above can overflow, and you'll need to adapt the result after the fact instead:

```
def ceilUIntDiv(a: UInt, b: UInt): UInt = {
  val c = a / b
  if (b * c == a) c else c + 1.U
}
```

Comment: UInt does not have a MaxValue and though it is possible in some case to determine the width of a UInt at compile time in the more general case widths may be inferred and not available.  This would probably argue for the second definition of ceilUIntDiv

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the expression `a / 2.U` is indeed `1.U`: if you apply `ceil` to `1.U` you'll get `1.U`.

Recall that this happens to `Int`s as well, as they use integer division:

```
scala> val result = Math.ceil(3 / 2)
result: Double = 1.0
```

What you should do is to enforce one of the division operands to be a `Double` likewise:

```
scala> val result = Math.ceil(3 / (2: Double))
result: Double = 2.0
```

And then just convert it back to `UInt`.

Comment: While you can use doubles in this example, in the more general case where one or both of the operands are wires, you will not be able to use the double trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
def ceilUIntDiv(a: UInt, b: UInt): UInt = {
    (a / b) + {if (a % b == 0.U) 0.U else 1.U}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.